# Trying to resize an entire page (IE shrink everything down)

Tags: html, css

I have a website that I made (without bootstrap or any or that stuff, and I am having an issue trying to scale everything down for people with a smaller screen resolution.  basically I'll want it to detect the size, and apply appropriate CSS classes to elements to scale everything down if under a specific width.  Right now I am just trying to build the CSS classes, and I am having some difficulties.  The closest I've gotten is shrinking all the content down using:

```
transform: scale(.75);
```

That works awesome on the actual content for resizing, but I'm left with a large padded field around the content. a bit hard to explain, but what I want is for the content to shrink, but the divs to still be 100% of the browser (so if there is a smaller browser it fits nicely without this stupid large padded area around the content)

Here is how it normally looks:
[image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGWRl.png)

and here is how it looks with the added CSS transform:[image2!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdWCd.png)

Any ideas for how to overcome this would be greatly appreciated, Also note I really don't care about my solution not working in IE9 or lower!

The basic output that I want is the equivelent of shrinking the browser zoom to 75% if that helps..

Comment: Are you suggesting that you don't want to use media queries, but instead are looking for a single universal css line that will scale everything?

Comment: Media queries would be alright, but yeah, I was really looking for a overall line or class I can make to handle things, before I get into it

Comment: If I take a book and shrink the entire thing by 3/4, does that make the *text* any easier to read? Or just smaller than before?

Comment: I don't mind that the text is smaller then before, I want all images and divs smaller then before (some of the divs have fixed widths)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your CSS is written, something as simple as this could work:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {font-size: 85%;}
}
```

If you have divs with `em` widths that will shrink their width, but you could change that via the media query above, perhaps setting their widths to `100%` etc.